# Ignoring Scripting variables in sqlcmd (Importing database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

I am having a database import being done form a SQL file and i see my content have some data that is conflicting with sqlcmd import. The following queries are the 2 scenarios i am encountering in my import.

```
INSERT INTO [users] ([id],[email],[title],[desc]) VALUES (1096,'sda@asfsdf.com',N'Shami Doc', N'This is profile of Shami who sends $(mid) message');
```

In this query am getting the following error...

```
'mid' scripting variable not defined.
```

Now in the second case...

```
INSERT INTO [users] ([id],[email],[title],[desc]) VALUES (1091,'das@dsa.com',N'Raj Doc', N'This is profile of Raj who sends $(m message');
```

Am getting Syntax Error. In actual i just want both data to be imported to users table with the same data defined... i mean the $(mid) should be imported just as text into that column and also $(m should be imported as same.

I tried using escape character backslash and it did not help. Can someone help me in this ? How can i have both above queries run without loosing that data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `-x` [SQLCMD command-line option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16#command-line-options) to ignore scripting variables when executing scripts where scripting variables need to be retained as data. For example:

```
SQLCMD -S YourServer -x -E -I -i YourScript.sql
```

Note this example also includes the `-I` option to set `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`, which is required for filtered indexes, indexed views and other features. SQLCMD initially sets `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`  off by default for backwards compatibility.